# Power of smooth Neyman Test

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-power

I would like to create code in R for POWER of Neyman's Smooth Test (with k components), which is generate from pdf: $C_1(u,0.4) = 1+0.4cos(\pi u), u\in (0,1)$. I generate $n$ observation and repeat in the loop 10 000 times. My code return only 0. What is wrong?

```
library(uniftest)
neyman <- function(n,k){
  x = 1 + 0.4*cos(pi*runif(n,0,1))
  a <- neyman.unif.test(x, nrepl=10000, k)$statistics
  sum(a > quantile(a, 0.95))/10^4
}
```

For example, when my input is 
`neyman(10,4)`, output is always 0.

Maybe you have another idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Because `neyman.unif.test(...)$statistics` is `NULL` and `sum(NULL > quantile(NULL, 0.95))/10^4` is equal to 0.

Comment: Even if there wasn't a typo in the line that generates `a`, wouldn't the result of `sum(a > quantile(a, 0.95))` always be 0 (because `a` contains a single value)?